# Зачем мы используем тут [].join?

Tags: javascript

Зачем тут мы используем [].join?Первый две строчки я никак не могу понять

```
function printArgs() {   
   arguments.join = [].join; // одолжили метод  (1)

   var argStr = arguments.join(':'); // (2)

   alert( argStr ); // сработает и выведет 1:2:3 
}

printArgs(1, 2, 3);
```

И что значит одолжили метод?

Comment: я так понимаю, вы взяли код [отсюда](https://learn.javascript.ru/call-apply#одалживание-метода). Так там же расписано как это работает (см. "Почему вызов сработает?")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция является таким же объектом. А значит ее можно присвоить переменной и потом вызывать через нее. Типичное применение - анонимные функции:

```
var a = function(){
    alert("hello");
} 
a();
```

В данном случае мы берем функцию, которая уже присутствует в другом объекте.

```
var a = function(){
    alert("hello");
} 
var b = a; //обратите внимание - без скобок.
b();
```

Тут используется такой же принцип, мы создали в объекте `arguments` переменную `join` и присвоили ей функцию массива(опять же обратите внимание на отсутствие скобок при обращении к функции - ее получение). Потом просто вызвали эту функцию и она сработала уже для объекта `arguments` как для массива.

Comment: почему тогда в строке arguments.join = [].join; нет скобок после [].join?

Comment: @GrommashTheHellscream, потому что берется ссылка на функцию, а не вызывается она

Comment: @GrommashTheHellscream, смотрите на `var b = a;`, а не на `b()`

Comment: @GrommashTheHellscream, я же написал) Мы ее не вызываем, а только получаем ее код без выполнения в другую переменную. Если бы мы подставили скобки, то она выполнилась и получили бы результат выполнения, а не саму функцию.

Comment: это я понял,но в твоем примере есть явно вызванная функция...ладно,я понял)спасибо за помощь)

Comment: @GrommashTheHellscream, ну так и в вашем коде есть явно вызванная функция: `arguments.join(':')`. У `arguments` нет метода `join`, сделав `arguments.join = [].join;` мы создали у `arguments` метод `join`, который копирует метод `join` массива. А дальше мы вызываем этот метод применительно к `arguments`. Т.е. и получается: `var b = a; b();` (или `arguments.join = [].join; var argStr = arguments.join(':');`)

Comment: @ВОРОН спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Так как объект [*arguments*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) не является массивом - у него нет функций, которые определены для класса [*Array*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).
Приведенный код - один из способов работать с этим объектом, как с массивом.

Comment: я могу копировать любой метод массива?например arguments.reduce=[].reduce?

Comment: @GrommashTheHellscream, да, методы можно копировать таким способом.

Comment: @GrommashTheHellscream, насчет "любой" не уверен, необходимо, чтобы внутренняя реализация текущего объекта поддерживала все методы, используемые в "одалживаемом" методе массива. Если это условие выполняется - метод использовать можно.

Comment: @BOPOH, _скопировать_ **методы** _можно_, проблемы только с вызовом могут возникнуть, но с классом _Array_ - не должно

Comment: ну это и имелось в виду. А то может получиться: скопировали метод, а он не работает, потом будут говорить: обманули, нельзя все подряд копировать.

Comment: @BOPOH, да уж, не исключено :-)